# Accessing Identi.ca Update Status

Tags: android

I am working through an Android tutorial from CommonsWare and cannot figure out why I am gettting my error.  Here is my code:

```
public class Patchy extends Activity {
public String DEB_TAG       = "Patchy.java";

private DefaultHttpClient client    = null;
private EditText user               = null;
private EditText password           = null;
private EditText status             = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.d(DEB_TAG, "inside oncreate");

    user        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user);
    password    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    status      = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.status);

    Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);

    send.setOnClickListener(onSend);

    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

private String getCredentials() {
    String u = user.getText().toString();
    String p = password.getText().toString();
    Log.d(DEB_TAG, "Value of u and p is " + u + "..." + p);
    String temp = Base64.encodeBytes((u+":"+p).getBytes());
    Log.d(DEB_TAG, "Value of temp is " + temp);
    return temp;
}

private void updateStatus() {
    try {
        String s = status.getText().toString();
        Log.d(DEB_TAG, "Value of status is " + s);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://identi.ca/api/statuses/update.json");

        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic" +getCredentials());

        List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", s));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form, HTTP.UTF_8));

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        String responseBody = client.execute(post, responseHandler);

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseBody);

    }catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e(DEB_TAG, "Exception in updateStatus()", t);
        goBlooey(t);
    }
}

private void goBlooey(Throwable t){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder
    .setTitle("Exception!")
    .setMessage(t.toString())
    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
    .show();
}
private View.OnClickListener onSend = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        updateStatus();

    }
};
```

}
and here is my LogCat error msgs:

> 08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738): Exception in updateStatus()
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at example.com.patchy.Patchy.updateStatus(Patchy.java:83)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at example.com.patchy.Patchy.access$0(Patchy.java:66)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at example.com.patchy.Patchy$1.onClick(Patchy.java:106)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2365)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4180)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6696)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3710)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:885)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:885)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:885)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:885)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1111)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1679)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1696)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4425)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   08-11 11:52:34.769: ERROR/Patchy.java(4738):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

On my phone a dialog pops up with the error "Exception. org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized"

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you are adding the credentials correctly? because this page requires a login and password.

Comment: please check your post with httpclient with credential and basic auth. better to write an application to test with httpclient.

Answer (score 0):

Questions regarding CommonsWare stuff should go to the [cw-android Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android). I nearly missed this question.

Make sure you are entering the correct username and password. Also, make sure that you clicked the link you got in the email from identi.ca -- you cannot use the API until that is done.

Comment: I am entering the correct username and password...double checked by log statement and using same credentials entering site from computer.  I can sign in over the Internet from my desktop.